# log json with date and time format with winston node logger

Tags: node.js, winston

I am trying to log json with winston that includes a timestamp, I have the following configuration:

```
'use strict';

import * as winston from 'winston';

const LOG = !!process.env.LOG;

export const { error, info, debug } = winston.createLogger({
  transports: [new winston.transports.Console()],
  silent: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test' && !LOG,
  format: winston.format.combine(
    winston.format.timestamp({
      format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
    }),
    winston.format.colorize({ all: true }),
    winston.format.simple()
  )
});
```

But it is logging messages like this:

```
info: connecting /closebanner {"timestamp":"2018-08-22 22:09:35"}
```

Only the timestamp is in json format and not the message.

Comment: It is not clear to me what You would like to achieve. Would like to have pasted log in json format?

Comment: @KarlR I have updated the question, let me know if that is any better.

Answer (score 8):

You can use winston json formatter:

```
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston');
const { combine, timestamp, json } = format;

const logger = createLogger({
  format: combine(
    timestamp({
      format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
    }),
    json(),
  ),
  transports: [new transports.Console()]
})
```

So for example:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  logger.info('request came');
  logger.error({ "errorMessage": "something went wrong " })
  return res.status(500).end();
})

app.listen(8080, () => {
  logger.info('app started')
})
```

When You request `localhost:8080` using `GET` HTTP method, it will result in:

```
{"message":"app started","level":"info","timestamp":"2018-08-23 00:56:48"}
{"message":"request came","level":"info","timestamp":"2018-08-23 00:56:54"}
{"message":{"errorMessage":"something went wrong"},"level":"error","timestamp":"2018-08-23 00:56:54"}
```

Please note that:

- colorize will not work with JSON - check [github discussion](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/1336)
- `format.simple()` is not needed since it is just another type (string literal), more info in [doc](https://github.com/winstonjs/logform/blob/master/simple.js)